# rabbitmq spring ReturnCallback and confimcallback

Tags: spring-rabbit

Below is my code:

```
rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback(new ReturnCallback() {
    @Override
    public void returnedMessage(Message message, int replyCode,
            String replyText, String exchange, String routingKey) {
        System.out.println("Received returnedMessage with result {}"
                + routingKey);

    }
});
rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(new ConfirmCallback() {
    @Override
    public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack,
            String cause) {
        System.out
                .println("*************************************************************************************"
                        + ack);
        //log.info("Received confirm with result {}", ack);

        System.out.println("Message received by broker");

    }
});
```

It not printing the message "Message received by broker".
Help me any one for same. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to configure the connection factory to support these features [see the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#template-confirms).

> For returned messages, the template’s mandatory property must be set to true, or the mandatory-expression must evaluate to true for a particular message. This feature requires a `CachingConnectionFactory` that has its `publisherReturns` property set to true
>
> ...
>
> For Publisher Confirms (aka Publisher Acknowledgements), the template requires a `CachingConnectionFactory` that has its `publisherConfirms` property set to true.
>
> ...